# binomial coefficient where k > n

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

For solving binomial coefficients we have use from formula

$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

This formula only works if n > k.

What happens if n < k? Is there another formula we need to use?

Comment: Correction.  The usual binomial coefficients (*which arise naturally from counting problems*) make sense when $n\geq k\geq 0$ and $n$ and $k$ are both integers.  Under usual contexts, we say $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k>n$.  A [generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series) can be made which no longer has quite as strong a parallel to the usual counting problems, but is instead used for more abstract problems.

Answer (score 5):

Your definition of "binomial coefficient" is too narrow. If $k$ is a nonnegative integer and $n$ is ***any real or complex number***, the binomial coefficient $\binom nk$ is defined as follows:
$$\binom nk=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}.$$
This is how the coefficient is understood in the ***general binomial theorem***:
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom nkx^k.$$

The formula $\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ only applies in the special case where $n$ is an integer and $n\ge k.$

To answer your question, note that $\binom nk$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ in the variable $n,$ and its zeros are $0,1,2,\dots,k-1.$ Thus $\binom nk=0$ if $n$ is a ***nonnegative integer*** $\lt k.$ On the other hand, $\binom nk\ne0$ if $n$ is negative or fractional or non-real.